# Как грамотно реализовать связь ManyToOne в Hiberante?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

**Есть две сущности:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BOOKS")
public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "TITLE")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "BOOK_PRICE")
    private int price;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "AUTHOR_ID")
    private Author author;
@Entity
@Table(name = "AUTHOR")
public class Author {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "YEARS")
    private String years;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "author", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Book> books;
```

Не работает сохранение книги в бд, пишет, что поле `author_id` не может быть `null`, хотя я пытался и вручную устанавливать автора:

```
@PostMapping("/add")
    public String add(@ModelAttribute("book")Book book){
        Author author = new Author();
        author.setName("Гоголь Н.В.");
        author.setYears("1809 - 1852");
        Set<Book> books = new HashSet<>();
        books.add(book);
        author.setBooks(books);
        book.setAuthor(author);

        bookService.addBook(book);

        return "redirect:/home";
    }
```

Я думаю дело в форме добавления. Но не понимаю как с неё можно отправить ещё и автора

```
<form name="book" action="/add" method="post">
    <p>Title</p>
    <input title="Title" type="text" name="title">
    <p>Price</p>
    <input title="Price" type="text" name="price">
    <input type="submit" value="Ok">
</form>
```

Comment: Вы добавили автора только на уровне кода и в базе его не существует соответственно и id пуст

Answer (score 0):

Вот что можно сказать про [`@ManyToOne`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ManyToOne.html) аннотацию.

> Определяет однозначную связь с другим сущностным классом, который
> имеет множественную множественность. Обычно нет необходимости
> указывать целевой объект явно, поскольку он обычно может быть выведен
> из типа объекта, на который делается ссылка. Если отношение является
> двунаправленным, сторона, не владеющая `@OneToMany`, должна
> использовать элемент `mappedBy`, чтобы указать поле отношения или
> свойство объекта, являющегося владельцем отношения.

Поскольку вы создаете сущность вручную, то у нее еще нет связи и поэтому такая сущность не представляет множественности. Для того, чтобы вывести целевой обект его не надо указывать, а нужно загрузить, тогда владеющая сторона будет учитывать тип объекта при сохранении, на который делается ссылка.